Prove that $\lim_{h \to 0} \int_{-\infty }^{+\infty } \left | f\left ( x+h \right ) -f\left ( x \right ) \right | ^{p} dx =0$
There's an interesting and absolutely valuable Mathematical conclusions that $$\lim_{h \to 0} \int_{-\infty }^{+\infty } \left | f\left ( x+h \right ) -f\left ( x \right )  \right | ^{p} dx=0$$ $$\left | f \right | ^{p} $$ is integrable on $$\left ( -\infty ,+\infty \right ) $$,p>0.
However,I can't work it out. I suppose that we should use Minkowski inequality or Holder inequality. Can you explain this clearly? Thank you very much!

Please put $$...$$ to render $\LaTeX$. Also, show us what you have tried for proving this result.

Yes, as @ultralegend5385 said, show us your attempts or thoughts about it. Or give some context. Moreover, you need to tell us what $f$ is. I suspect, that $f \in L^p(\mathbb{R})$, but if not, this could be even more interesting :)

Try to prove that for continuous functions with bounded support.

Oh thanks for guiding:)

Your English appears to be fairly good, but what is 'productible'?

Is there any data whether f(x) is monotonically increasing or not?

Ah, not given: ( @Gwen

Thank you very much@AnneBauval.
